# The trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>`

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, reqwest

I'm trying to run basic `reqwest` [example](https://github.com/seanmonstar/reqwest/blob/master/examples/simple.rs):

```rust
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate tokio;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), reqwest::Error> {
    let res = reqwest::Client::new()
        .get("https://hyper.rs")
        .send()
        .await?;

    println!("Status: {}", res.status());

    let body = res.text().await?;

    println!("Body:\n\n{}", body);

    Ok(())
}
```

Error that I'm getting:

```
   --> src/main.rs:6:15
    |
6   |       let res = reqwest::Client::new()
    |  _______________^
7   | |         .get("https://hyper.rs")
8   | |         .send()
9   | |         .await?;
    | |______________^ the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `std::result::Result<reqwest::Response, reqwest::Error>`
```

Rust version: `rustc 1.39.0 (4560ea788 2019-11-04)`

Library versions:

```
reqwest = "0.9.22"
tokio = { version = "0.2.0-alpha.6", features = ["full"] }
```

Does anybody know what is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59101974/2722968), just in reverse. You are using `reqwest-0.9`, which is using the blocking interface by default. Update to `reqwest-0.10` to get the async interface.

If you can't update to `reqwest-0.10`, the async interface in `reqwest-0.9` is in `reqwest::async`. E.g. `reqwest::async::Client::new(...)`.

Comment: Thansk a lot, it helped! In my case, the working combination of `tokio` and `reqwest` are `reqwest = "0.10.0-alpha.2"` and `tokio = { version = "0.2.0-alpha.6" }`