# Async loop on a new thread in rust: the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `()`

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I know this question has been asked many times, but I still can't figure out what to do (more below).

I'm trying to spawn a new thread using `std::thread::spawn` and then run an async loop inside of it.

The async function I want to run:

```
#[tokio::main] 
pub async fn pull_tweets(pg_pool2: Arc<PgPool>, config2: Arc<Settings>) {
    let mut scheduler = AsyncScheduler::new();

    scheduler.every(10.seconds()).run(move || {
        let arc_pool = pg_pool2.clone();
        let arc_config = config2.clone();
        async {
            pull_from_main(arc_pool, arc_config).await;
        }
    });

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        loop {
            scheduler.run_pending().await;
            tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        }
    });
}
```

Spawning a thread to run in:

```
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || async {
        pull_tweets(pg_pool2, config2).await;
    });
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0277]: `()` is not a future
  --> src/main.rs:89:9
   |
89 |         pull_tweets(pg_pool2, config2).await;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `()` is not a future
   |
   = help: the trait `std::future::Future` is not implemented for `()`
   = note: required by `poll`
```

[The last comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46625376/the-trait-bound-futuresfuture-is-not-satisfied-when-using-tcpconnectionn) does an amazing job at generalizing the problem. It seems at some point a return value is expected that implements `IntoFuture` and I don't have that. I tried adding `Ok(())` to both the closure and the function, but no luck.

- Adding into closure does literally nothing
- Adding into async function gives me a new, but similar-sounding error:

```
`Result<(), ()>` is not a future
```

Then I noticed that the answer specifically talks about [extension functions](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.0-alpha/futures/trait.FutureExt.html), which I'm not using. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720321/understanding-error-trait-futuresfuturefuture-is-not-implemented-for) also talks about extension functions.

Some other SO answers:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748810/why-do-i-get-the-trait-bound-future-is-not-satisfied-when-using-await-or-in-a) is caused by a missing `async`.
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125573/the-trait-stdfuturefuture-is-not-implemented-for-stdresultresultreqw) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59101974/the-trait-stdopstry-is-not-implemented-for-impl) are `reqwest` library specific.

So none seem to work. Could someone help me understand 1)why the error exists here and 2)how to fix it?

Note 1: All of this can be easily solved by replacing `std::thread::spawn` with `tokio::task::spawn_blocking`. But I'm purposefully experimenting with thread spawn as per [this article](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/).

Note 2: Broader context on what I want to achieve: I'm pulling 150,000 tweets from twitter in an async loop. I want to compare 2 implementations: running on the main runtime vs running on separate thread. The latter is where I struggle.

Note 3: in my mind threads and async tasks are two different primitives that don't mix. Ie spawning a new thread doesn't affect how tasks behave and spawning a new task only adds work on existing thread. Please let me know if this worldview is mistaken (and what I can read).

Comment: You **await** `pull_tweets()`. At the same time, `#[tokio::main]` tells tokio that `pull_tweets()` is a "main" function, i.e. a sync function that will create an executor and block on it. You cannot have both: it must be either async or main. Just get rid of `#[tokio::main]` and see how it works then.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I peaked the idea of adding #[tokio::main] to a non-main function in another SO post I can't find right now. Your solution makes the code compile but it doesn't do anything unfortunately (ie the scheduler doesn't run). But going the other way around - removing async/await and keeping #[tokio::main] actually works!

Comment: Yeah, `thread::spawn(|| async ...)` doesn't make sense, you'd need something like `block_on()` there. You're right that it's ok to use `tokio::main` for something that's not `main()`, it's just a tool that converts an async function to sync. Note however that the default tokio executor is multi-threaded, so while you might consider threads and async different worlds, tokio doesn't agree, at least not by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#[tokio::main]` converts your function into the following:

```rust
#[tokio::main] 
pub fn pull_tweets(pg_pool2: Arc<PgPool>, config2: Arc<Settings>) {
    let rt = tokio::Runtime::new();
    rt.block_on(async {
        let mut scheduler = AsyncScheduler::new();
        // ...
    });
}
```

Notice that it is a *synchronous* function, that spawns a new runtime and runs the inner future to completion. You do not `await` it, it is a separate runtime with it's own dedicate thread pool and scheduler:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        pull_tweets(pg_pool2, config2);
    });
}
```

---

Note that your original example was wrong in another way:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || async {
        pull_tweets(pg_pool2, config2).await;
    });
}
```

Even if `pull_tweets` *was* an async function, the thread would not do anything, as all you do is create another future in the `async` block. The created future is not executed, because futures are *lazy* (and there is no executor context in that thread anyways).

I would structure the code to spawn the runtime directly in the new thread, and call any `async` functions you want from there:

```rust
#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
            .enable_all()
            .build()
            .unwrap();
        rt.block_on(async {
            pull_tweets(pg_pool2, config2).await;
        });
    });
}

pub async fn pull_tweets(pg_pool2: Arc<PgPool>, config2: Arc<Settings>) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for the comment! The part about removing .await was on point. I had to do one extra bit (which is weird, and I think is clokwerk library specific) - I had to remove the tokio::spawn block around the loop (so keep just the loop). Then everything works. Btw the #[tokio::main] with no .await also works.